# Creating a TS output from a very short MP4 (AVC) input

Tags: ffmpeg

I tried to use ffmpeg to convert a small (2 frames) MP4 file with AVC encoding as follows:

ffmpeg -y -noautorotate -loglevel 99 -i inputfile.mp4 -threads 0 -map_chapters -1 -write_tmcd 0 -metadata location= -max_muxing_queue_size 2000 -f mpegts -filter_complex "[0:v:0]yadif=deint=interlaced,scale=162:288:flags=bicubic,setdar=0.5625[main];[main]concat=n=1:v=1:a=0[cat_v]" -an -sn -map "[cat_v]" -vcodec libx264 -profile:v baseline -level 3 -b:v 272k -maxrate 272k -bufsize 2448k -preset medium -x264opts ref=1:keyint=90:no_scenecut -r 30.0 -vsync 1 -metadata:s:v rotate= -pix_fmt yuv420p outputfile.ts

But what I get is a TS file that cannot be played by any player. I tried using TSReaderLite to analyze the outputfile.ts but found the limited information I get is this: 4 PIDs in all - a PID 0x000 - PAT (Program Metadata), a PID 0x0011 - SDT (service Description Table), a PID 0x0100 - unknown, a PID 0x1000 - unknown.

Is there a known issue with TS outputs when we have such short files?

Comment: Does ffplay play the output?

Comment: No, I get this message:                                                                             
[mpeg @ 0x7fa154827000] Format mpeg detected only with low score of 25, misdetection possible!
outputfile.ts: could not find codec parameters

Comment: Share the input.

Comment: What is the best way to share files in this forum ? Never done this before

Comment: Upload to Google Drive/Dropbox..etc and share a link

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1LtAdEvtAT7TL5LIvRQ6UtSSoSFOU9-ze?usp=sharing      - This folder contains the input as well as output files

Answer (score 0):

Add `-mpegts_flags pat_pmt_at_frames`. The default interval is 40 packets, which is too long for short files such as these. You may get a decoding error but that's from the stream probe. It doesn't affect playback here.